# Creating plain text pages in osCommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am creating navigation items in osCommerce like "privacy" and "terms and conditions" etc.

Is there any way that I can install a module which can help in creating simple text pages just like we create articles in Joomla!? (Otherwise, I have to copy the existing PHP file and hack around with some changes.)

I know PHP and Joomla! but very new to osCommerce which I have to use.

Comment: Do you have admin/information_manager.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Why use osCommerce at all? If you are not being forced to use it, use Joomla with VirtueMart or other e-commerce extension. osCommerce is very bad at handling non-ecommerce pages.

*edit*

Bummer. since you are stuck with OSC, then you will have to look to a contribution for this.

For OSC Online Merchant:

http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/5869

http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/4064

For osCommerce:

http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,3476

http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,909

Comment: actually the site is already build using that and i have to edit it . i have no option